How to Restrict MFA Based on Country Code in Azure AD B2C Custom Policy?
I’m working on an Azure AD B2C custom policy where I need to restrict users from performing Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) based on the country code of their phone number. The phone number is already stored in the user’s profile.
Requirement:
Users with a UK phone number (+44) should proceed to the MFA step.
Users with non-UK phone numbers should be restricted and shown an error message.
I have followed the below github example which is basically for signup flow so I tweaked it for my purpose, but it seems that the strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber defined in my base policies is not being set.
My second orchestration step is as follows:
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId"/>
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

The AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId technical profile is defined in the base policies as follows:
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
            <!-- Optional claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" /> -->
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>


Any help to tackle this issue would be much appreciated. I am unable to use the strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber or Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber claims to retrieve the phone number associated with the user after sign-in and prior to the MFA screen.

You can use Claims Transformation to extract the country code from the phone number claim and then use an AssertClaims validation technical profile to restrict MFA based on the extracted country code.
